# Call a function inside the directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Trying to call a function inside the directive:

```
    angular.module('abc').directive('autocomp', function ()   {
    return {
            replace: true,
            scope: true,
            controller: 'Controller',
            controllerAs: 'ctrl',
            srchtxt: '@',                
             scope: {
                    src: '&'
             },
                templateUrl: '/dom/abc/auto.html',
                link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
                    scope.$watch('srchtxt', function () {
                        scope.src(scope.srchtxt});
                    });
                }
           }
         });
```

==========================================================================
Method inside the controller:

```
    function search(srchtxt) {
         console.log('srchText:', srchText);            
     }
```

===========================================================================
    HTML:

```
<abc src="rc.search()"></abc>
```

I am writing a directive for the md-autocomplete control to which method name can be passed as attributes from the HTML pagee, and then try to execute the method inside the directive.
There's a watch on the textchange in the control in which I call the method to be executed (scope.src(scope.srchText}))

When I type in something into the autocomplete control I get the following error:
TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'rc' in g

Could any one please suggest on what am I missing or doing wrong ?

Comment: Try changing `scope.datasrc(scope.searchText});` ==> `scope.datasrc(scope.searchText);`

Comment: That doesn't work either

Answer (score 0):

When you use `&` to bind controller method into directive, you have to declare exact parameter in your html like

```
<sml-auto-complete datasrc="cr.query(searchText)"></sml-auto-complete>
//                                        ^
```

Then when you call this method from directive you need to pass the parameter as object like

```
scope.$watch('searchText', function () {
    scope.datasrc({searchText: scope.searchText}); //not simply scope.datasrc(scope.searchText)
});
```

Check this [demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/Z47T5IuaOZV7BBZeHd0f?p=preview)

Comment: Reza, Thank you very much for the comments, it worked, I had tried this before but didn't try both of the above answers simultaneously. Thank you again

Comment: The "searchText" parameter is the value of the attributes in my templateUrl:

Comment: <md-input-container>
    <md-autocomplete md-input-name="quayVisitAutocomp" md-input-minlength="1"
                  md-selected-item-change="" md-search-text-change=null md-autofocus="false"
                  md-selected-item="cr.QuayVisitId" md-search-text="searchText"  <<-------

Comment: Do you have any suggestions if this is right way to do it ?

Comment: If it works you should accept the answer. I think there should be some `config` option something like autocomplete config, wrap all the configuration into single config object, otherwise there is too much config into html

Comment: I want to pass a value from my HTML to the autocomplete directive, if I use md-min-length={{mdminlength}}, (mdminlength is the value passsed from HTML) it gives me an errror

Comment: Create an object like `autoCompleteConfig = {mdMinLength: 1, mdSelectedItemChange:'', mdSearchTextChange:null, mdAutofocus="false" mdSelectedItem="cr.QuayVisitId", mdSearchText="searchText"}` then pass this object to your directive like `<sml-auto-complete datasrc="cr.query(searchText)" config='autoCompleteConfig '></sml-auto-complete>` in directive scope `scope:{src: '&', config: '='}`. Now inside directive you have all the options like `scope.config.mdMinLength`

Comment: Where do I declare this object : `autoCompleteConfig = {mdMinLength: 1, mdSelectedItemChange:'', mdSearchTextChange:null, mdAutofocus="false" mdSelectedItem="cr.QuayVisitId", mdSearchText="searchText"}`, I want these values to be configurable, so that any one who uses this directive can pass his own values, this means if I have 4 instances of this directive on a page, I will need to have 4 `autoCompleteConfig` sets ?

Comment: In your controller where do you define `cr.query(searchText`

Comment: What if there are multiple instances of the directive on the same page? I need to create multiple instances of that object

Comment: I mean, how and where to create multiple instances of `autoCompleteConfig` object an set their values

Comment: For multiple instance you need multiple configuration in your controller like `$scope.personAutoCompleteConfig`,  `$scope.countryAutoCompleteConfig` and in your directive like `<sml-auto-complete datasrc="cr.query(searchText)" config='personAutoCompleteConfig'></sml-auto-complete>`, `<sml-auto-complete datasrc="cr.query(searchText)" config='countryAutoCompleteConfig'></sml-auto-complete>`